# Is the interaction with a static field elastic?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics

Suppose you have a plane and connect it to negative voltage.
If an electron is incoming toward it it will interact with the electrostatic field
and be rejected. Will the electron loose energy or the hit is elastic?

Comment: Who has given me a minus without any reason?

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

["Collisions" in which the objects do not touch each other, such as Rutherford scattering (or the slingshot orbit of a satellite off a planet), are elastic collisions. In atomic or nuclear scattering, the collisions are **typically elastic because the repulsive Coulomb force keeps the particles out of contact** with each other.]

This in my opinion answers the question I asked. The electron will not loose energy!

Comment: In site hyperphysics.